# Dask Distributed Ensure New Workers Get Module Uploaded by upload_file

Tags: python, distributed, dask

Is there any way to ensure that new workers get a python package sent with upload_file when they join the cluster like dask-ml does when scattering the data ie:

```
# Serialize the training data only once to each worker
with parallel_backend('dask', scatter=[digits.data, digits.target]):
    search.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
```

If new worker joins the cluster while a job is running they do not get the module and error out.

I suppose one way to deal with loading R&D modules using an EFS mount which symlinks to site-packages that the workers, Jupyter notebook server, and scheduler mount. Though it would be nice to just use something alone the lines of upload_file.